Hardware serial baudrate inconsistent between Arduino nano and standalone 328P
I have a 328P (328P-AUR to be specific, [link]), and in the schematic below is how I've implemented it to a PCB:

Uploading a program works fine, but I hink there is an issue with the clock source, since the programs seem to run too slow, and timing-critical protocols like the hardware UART/Serial transmits at only 16th of it's intended baudrate. This is the program I'm testing the serial with:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
uint8_t count = 0;
void loop() {
  Serial.print("Num:");
  Serial.println(count++);
  delay(1000);
}

So in the case of Serial.begin(9600); here, the microcontroller actually transmits at only 600 bauds, or in the case of Serial.begin(115200);, the actual transmission rate is only 7200.
I'm currently using an Arduino Uno with the "Arduino as ISP" programming mode, but this method doesn't allow me to set any of the fuses in the 328P... I do have a dedicated ICSP programmer that only works on Microchip studio, which I could try to do this with, but I'm not certain of the fuse value i'd have to set for it to work correctly with the 16MHz external crystal I have connected to the 328P.
Is there anythwing wrong with my design, or is this just a limitation when uploading with Arduino IDE? If so, what values do I configre the fuses with for this hardware?

A raw ATmega328P chip had the CKDIV8 (divide by 8) fuse programmed and to use the internal 8MHz oscillator. You should be able to use AVRDUDE together with "Arduino as ISP" to change the fuse settings. Alternatively, you could use minicore https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore (option no bootloader) to set the fuses and then upload code.
Your design appears to match the Arduino Uno and the fuse settings can be found in the boards.txt file:

uno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xff
uno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xde
uno.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05

EDIT
The standard Uno fuse settings above assume that you are going to use a bootloader of 512 bytes. If, however, you are not using a bootloader and always use an ISP programmer, then the fuse BOOTRST should be unprogrammed. This frees 512 bytes flash memory for your program. It also prevents an undefined situation if your sketch is large enough to stray into the bootloader area at the high end of the flash memory. You can use this fuse calculator to determine the correct settings: https://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega328p

I tried both methods and they worked. I also tried MicrochipStudio with AVRISP MK2 and I copied the fuse settings from the AVRDUDE output from your first suggestion and that also worked just fine. Thank you!
